# + string concat operator with a null operand

Tags: c#, .net

A co-worker showed me a very strange behavior and I'd like to know if someone could explain me why.

A basic constructor with 2 string params:

```
    public MyClass(string str1, string str2)
    {
        this.s1 = str1;
        this.s2 = str2;
        this.s3 = Method(str2 + "._className", str1);
    }
```

Method is:

```
public string Method(string key, string defaultValue)
{
    List<string> list = _vars[key];
    if (list == null) return defaultValue;
    string res = "";
    foreach (string s in list)
    {
        if (res != "") res += ",";
        res += s;
    }
    return res;
}
```

When this ctor is called within an aspx page with `str2` as `null`, all works fine because if an operand of string concatenation `+` is `null`, an empty string is substituted.

But when this ctor is called with `str2` as `null` in a background thread, a `NullReferenceException` is fired.

The problem was solved by testing `str2 != null` before using it, but I'd really like to know why the same code sometimes fires an exception, sometimes not!

Here is the stack trace:

```
Exception: System.NullReferenceException 
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
StackTrace: 
at MyClass..ctor(String str1, String str2) 
at AbandonedCartsNotificationJob.NotifyAbandonedCarts() in AbandonedCartsNotificationJobPartial.cs:line 39 
at AbandonedCartsNotificationJob.work() in AbandonedCartsNotificationJob.cs:line 15 
at MyRuntime.JobManager.run() 
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state) 
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData) 
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) 
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) 
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: I feel like something else is going on here. What is `this.s2` used for? What is the stack trace? Can you post reproducible code for us to test with? Where are you doing the null check? Is it before instantiating `MyClass` or before executing `Method` or at the beginning of the constructor?

Comment: Are you sure you've tracked the issue down to the correct piece of code? What does `Method` do?

Comment: Are you sure? you tried same combination in Background thread?

Comment: where that exception thrown ?

Comment: Also, this is in an ASPX page. Is your background thread attempting to access resources from the main thread that's part of the page-request-response cycle? It's plausible that the page has already served its content or you're attempting to access other objects outside of that normal cycle and getting an exception elsewhere. EDIT: And what's going on with `str1`? It's irrelevant information based on what you're describing. Have you changed its input or does it affect anything?

Comment: Are you checking `str2` for null only for the `Method` call or before setting it to `s2` as well?

Comment: I don't know about this.  I just tried it with `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new MyClass("foo", null)); task.Wait();` and it worked fine.

Comment: I edited the original question with stackTrace & Method implementation. I can't exactly post a reproductible test here cause its a small part of a very large library.

Comment: @Sylv21: Is this with debugging mode _turned on_? (that is compiler optimizations turned _off_) As it stands, I don't see anything in your constructor that could have produced that stack trace. Only via method inlining (because of being compiled for release mode with optimizations) I think could that have happened. (either that, or you have not posted the _actual code_ of your constructor)

Comment: the only think I see is _vars[key], _vars might be null, can you check it?

Comment: As a side node, please replace your `foreach`-loop with a proper call to `String.Join` for sanity's sake :-)

Comment: @Sylv21: What happens if you run your `MyClass` in a background thread but pass a _non-null_ value in for its constructor parameters? Does it still throw?

Comment: the stack trace is obtained in the event log via health monitoring event fire in the bg thread when an exception is caught. The problem was solved (see my answer to Marwie below) I just found this behavior really weird hence my question here

Comment: @Sylv21: How/where/when do you assign the `_vars` object? EDIT: Going out on a limb here: is `_vars` assigned statically and either hasn't been initialized yet _and/or_ adorned with the `[ThreadStatic]` attribute?

Comment: Method as a one-liner: `return string.Join(",", _vars[key] ?? Enumerable.Repeat(defaultValue, 1));` And also, how come you don't have a line number for the initial `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: @flindeberg Why not just `return string.Join(",", _vars[key] ?? new []{defaultValue});` :-)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair It seems to blow in the ctor though, and not in Method =/

Comment: @DominicKexel Because I like the unknown implementation fuzziness which comes with using Enumerable.Repeat :) (or well, honestly, reflex I guess?)

Comment: @flindeberg: I think `Method` is being inlined.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Even if it is, shouldn't the point of exception be correct due the pdb? That is, if I've understood the language based inlining correctly.

Comment: Ah, it's public, ie it wont be inlined at all though...

Comment: @flindeberg: I'm not 100% positive, but I don't think so. Even with a PDB, when methods are inlined due to optimizations, they might not match that information. _I think_. I could be wrong; it's been a while since I've had to deal with method-inlined stack traces in ASP.NET.

Comment: Between the method's size, loops, concatenation, if condition, it might not be inlined anyway. I still suspect we aren't seeing the whole picture here. @Sylv21: Is `s3` a property that does any work in its setter?

Comment: Thanks all for your answers ! I'll change the Method implementation in regards of your remarks (I agree it's very bad). I think the real problem may not be str2 being null but by not calling Method if it's the case we avoid the real problem. I'll try to investigate and I'll post here any new information I get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was an obscure bug in the .NET Framework's implementation of string concatenation, but it only affected concatenations of 4 objects, where one of the objects is non-null *and* provided an override of `ToString` that returned null. Clearly that situation isn't the case here.

This situation is most likely caused by one of the following:

- `_vars` is null when `Method` is called
- Due to a misuse of `_vars` in a multi-threaded application, the internal state of `_vars` has been corrupted, resulting in a `NullReferenceException` when operator `[]` is used.

Comment: It was indeed a problem with _var, Method was not initially designed to be used in multi-thread mode.

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies in the implementation of the `Method` Object. Since the [+ Operator implementation interprets a null value as an empty string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx).  The actuall null value never enters the constructor when set in `str2`. On the Opposite, `str1` directly enters as null value and may depending on the implementation cause a null reference exception.

Comment: It's not str1 that causes the exception cause we solved the problem by changing :

    this.s3 = Method(str2 + "._className", str1);

in :

this.s3 = str2 != null ? Method(str2 + "._className", str1) : str1;

Comment: @Sylv21 maybe when `str2` is `null`, `str1` is **also** `null`, meaning  you don't see that `str1` is `null` because the check on `str2` stopped it. Have you actually tried to debug the code and checked what variable is null?

Comment: str1 is only used as a default value returned by Method (see the edited question).